# Compare embed title discord js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Im trying to compare an embed's title on discord and if the embed has some keywords, the bot would ping a role like `@eveyone`.

My part of the code where I do that is:

```js
keywords = "Apple","Bananas";

if (msg.embed.title.includes(keywords)){
  console.log(`The embed contains ${keywords}`)
}
```

I tried to scrape an embed's title.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method like this. It tests whether at least one element in the `keywords` array passes the test implemented by the provided function. The callback function checks if the word is included in the title.

```js
const keywords = ['Apple', 'Bananas'];

if (keywords.some((w) => msg.embeds[0].title.includes(w))) {
  console.log(`The embed contains at least one of ${keywords.join(', ')}`);
}
```

If you want to make it case insensitive, you could use `.toLowerCase()`:

```js
const keywords = ['Apple', 'Bananas'];

if (keywords.some(
  (w) => msg.embeds[0].title.toLowerCase().includes(w.toLowerCase()))
) {
  console.log(`The embed contains at least one of ${keywords.join(', ')}`);
}
```